# Create wildcard index in CosmosDB Emulator with MongoDB API

Tags: indexing, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am unable to create a wildcard index on all properties like mentioned in documentation:

```
db.getCollection("documents").createIndex({
    "$**": 1
})
```

I am also unable to create it in UI because UI for MongoAPI is not yet supported in CosmosDB emulator. I can create same index in CosmosDb on Azure portal.
Error I am getting is:

```
Index keys cannot contain an empty field.
```

Not sure whether I am missing something or it's not supported. Also my collections are empty and created from code.

Comment: TIL there is such a thing as a wildcard index.  Seems like a slightly bizarre concept.

Comment: Since I am starting to develop the application and data structure is not yet fully available it seems like a good fit. Without that I can't even sort by dynamic fields unlike in pure MongoDB or SQL Server.

Comment: Is it possible the problem comes from your database version? [This doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-indexing#wildcard-indexes-version-32) mentions wildcard  index only support for version 4.0 or 3.6.

Comment: And the cosmosdb emulator hasn't updated for a long time, it always has many limitations.

Comment: Actually I created the database with the emulator and I am not sure which version it used  but I hope it is at least 3.6.